# Convert Lua to C#

Tags: c#, lua

I have the following Lua code I would like to conver to C#. The only problem I  are the strings operations. I don't know how to translate them to C#:

```
if (classaddress~=nil) and (classname~=nil) then
  classname=classname:match "^%s*(.-)%s*$"
  if (classname~='') then
    local r=string.find(classname, "[^%a%d_.]", 1) 
    if (r==nil) or (r>=5) then
      return currentaddress, classaddress, classname
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you write the psuedo code of what this does?

Comment: That's the question. I have no idea what  "^%s*(.-)%s*$" or  "[^%a%d_.]" does. I just know that classaddress is an integer and classname is a string. Then the string classname is checked, but i don't know against what as I don't know much about LUA.

Comment: @Baldik: Lua is not an acronym; it's a proper name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strings in your code are [patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1). They are like Regular Expressions, but a little bit less mighty. The first match matches the whole string, excluding spaces at the start and end of the string, so it behaves like `Trim`. The second pattern is used to find the first character that's not a letter, a digit, an underscore (`_`) or a dot (`.`). Translated to C#, it might look like this:

```
public class MyReturnObject {
    public MyReturnObject(int currentAddress, int classAddress, string className) {
        // ...
    }
}

public MyReturnObject ParseStuff(int? classAddress, string className, int currentAddress) {
    if(classAddress.HasValue && className != null) {
        className = className.Trim();
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(className)) {
            var r = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(className, @"[^\a\d_.]")?.Index;

            if(!r.HasValue || r.Value >= 5) {
                return new MyReturnObject(currentAddress, classAddress.Value, className);
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you also for the explanation!